# Pyspark partitionBy: How do I partition my data and then select columns

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': [5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to partition the data by 'col1', but I don't want the 'col1' variable to be in the final data. Is this possible?

The below code would partition by col1, but how do I ensure 'col1' doesn't appear in the final data?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.write.partitionBy("col1").mode("overwrite").csv("file_path/example.csv", 
header=True)
```

Final data would be two files that look like:

```
d1 = {'col2': [3], 'col3': [5]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2 = {'col2': [4], 'col3': [6]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

Seems simple, but i can't figure out how I can partition the data, but leave the variable used to partition out of the final csv?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ONce you partition the data using

```
df.write.partitionBy("col1").mode("overwrite").csv("file_path/example.csv", header=True)
```

There will be partitions based on your col1.

Now while reading the dataframe you can specify which columns you want to use like:

```
df=spark.read.csv('path').select('col2','col3')
```

Comment: I see what you mean but I’m writing the csv to blob storage. The data is then used in an application, so ‘col1’ needs to be taken out of the data before it lands in the file

Comment: in file the column will not be present and if you are reading the file directly from your application then col1 will not be present in that but if you read folder level data using pyspark then only col1 will be present in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for spark 2.4.0 using scala api-

```
    val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(Seq(Row(1,3,5),Row(2,4,6))),
      StructType(Seq.range(1,4).map(f => StructField("col" + f, DataTypes.IntegerType))))

    df.write.partitionBy("col1")
      .option("header", true)
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .csv("/<path>/test")
```

It creates 2 files as below-

1. col1=1 with actual partition file as below-

```
col2,col3
3,5
```

2. col2=2 with actual partition file as below-

```
col2,col3
4,6
```

same for col2=2

I'm not seeing col1 in the file.

in python-

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(col1=[1, 2], col1=[3, 4], col3=[5, 6])])
df.write.partitionBy('col1').mode('overwrite').csv(os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(), 'data'))
```

api doc - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Comment: Is there a way to do this using python API?

Comment: it should be on similar line using pyspark apis

Comment: updated my answer using python, haven't tested it but it should work